# Check if raw data is corrupted

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, parsing

I am saving .tmp files containing this raw data (a Buffer)

```
[{"start_bin_value":"000180000","end_bin_value":"000180999","card_length":"16","card_brand":"006","service_type":"002","card_organization":"003","cdv_validation":"1","issuer_region":"1","bin_country":"840","issuer_bin":"400087","cft_flag":"000","mt_flag":"001","funding_source":"D","restricted_use":"A"},{"start_bin_value":"021502670","end_bin_value":"021502909","card_length":"19","card_brand":"006","service_type":"002","card_organization":"003","cdv_validation":"0","issuer_region":"1","bin_country":"840","issuer_bin":"400087","cft_flag":"000","mt_flag":"001","funding_source":"D","restricted_use":"A"},{"start_bin_value":"221572830","end_bin_value":"221572839","card_length":"16","card_brand":"006","service_type":"002","card_organization":"003","cdv_validation":"0","issuer_region":"1","bin_country":"840","issuer_bin":"400087","cft_flag":"000","mt_flag":"000","funding_source":"D","restricted_use":"A"},{"start_bin_value":"308952000","end_bin_value":"308969999","card_length":"19","card_brand":"006","service_type":"002","card_organization":"003","cdv_validation":"0","issuer_region":"1","bin_country":"840","issuer_bin":"400087","cft_flag":"000","mt_flag":"001","funding_source":"D","restricted_use":"A"}]
```

Now i would like to check (everytime i read these files) that the content / raw data is not corrupted/broken and i able to parse it somehow

How can i do practically?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of corruption are you worried about? Random? Intentional changes by someone?

Comment: Save some kind of CRC of the source file to some other file/database/place and check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify what you mean with *corrupted/broken*, but if you only want to check whether you can parse it, just read it with [`fs.readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) and use a [`try...catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) block around [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```js
/*

In Node.js you would do:

const fs = require('fs');
const rawData = fs.readFileSync("path/to/data.json");

*/

let rawData = `
[{"start_bin_value":"000180000","end_bin_value":"000180999","card_length":"16","card_brand":"006","service_type":"002","card_organization":"003","cdv_validation":"1","issuer_region":"1","bin_country":"840","issuer_bin":"400087","cft_flag":"000","mt_flag":"001","funding_source":"D","restricted_use":"A"},{"start_bin_value":"021502670","end_bin_value":"021502909","card_length":"19","card_brand":"006","service_type":"002","card_organization":"003","cdv_validation":"0","issuer_region":"1","bin_country":"840","issuer_bin":"400087","cft_flag":"000","mt_flag":"001","funding_source":"D","restricted_use":"A"},{"start_bin_value":"221572830","end_bin_value":"221572839","card_length":"16","card_brand":"006","service_type":"002","card_organization":"003","cdv_validation":"0","issuer_region":"1","bin_country":"840","issuer_bin":"400087","cft_flag":"000","mt_flag":"000","funding_source":"D","restricted_use":"A"},{"start_bin_value":"308952000","end_bin_value":"308969999","card_length":"19","card_brand":"006","service_type":"002","card_organization":"003","cdv_validation":"0","issuer_region":"1","bin_country":"840","issuer_bin":"400087","cft_flag":"000","mt_flag":"001","funding_source":"D","restricted_use":"A"}]
`;

try {
  const data = JSON.parse(rawData);
  
  console.log('Data parsed OK!');
} catch(err) {
  console.error('Data could not be parsed!');
  console.error(err);
}

// Corrupt it so that it's no longer valid JSON:
rawData = rawData.slice(0, -10);

try {
  const data = JSON.parse(rawData);
  
  console.log('Data parsed OK!');
} catch(err) {
  console.error('Data could not be parsed!');
  console.error(err);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just The original raw data must be OK and parsable, only in case of file corruption detect it's not OK